# Histogram / Density plot from overlapping uneven bins and counts

Tags: r

I have data where sample counts have been pre-calculated for bins across a range, and the bins are overlapping and uneven sizes.  Looks something like:

```
x2 <- data.frame("BinFrom" = c(1,1,2,2,4,4,4,5,5,5,8,8,8,9,11,14,17,18,19), 
                "BinTo" = c(3,6,4,8,5,8,6,10,12,6,7,15,11,10,20,20,18,19,20), 
                "Count" = c(1000,2400,15,2000,20,3800,10,6000,4200,10,25,3000,2800,10,1300,9000,10,5,40))
```

I wish to generate a histogram and density plot for these data.  Is there a way to do this?

ggdensity etc expect the expanded data.  I attempted to force that format by expanding on the mid-point of the bins, e.g.:

```
x2 <- x2 %>% mutate(MidBin = BinFrom + ((BinTo-BinFrom)/2))
xp <- x2 %>% expandRows(., "Count") 
ggdensity(xp, "MidBin")
```

but this loses important data, and is not possible with my actual data frame as the row expansion exhausts the vector memory.

All help appreciated

Comment: If that comment intends to add information to the question, edit the question. If it's an answer, post an answer to your question and accept that answer of yours.

Answer (score 0):

Create new matrix and count base-overlap

```
base=cbind.data.frame(base=c(min(x2$BinFrom):max(x2$BinTo)))
base$overlap=sapply(base$base,function(x) sum(x2$Count[x >= x2$BinFrom & x <= x2$BinTo ]))
```

plot

```
ggplot(base,aes(x=base,y=overlap))+geom_bar(stat = "identity")
#or
ggplot(base,aes(x=base,y=overlap))+geom_area(alpha=0.25)
```